# AngularJS $resource: redirected requests get cancelled

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I have an issue when accessing a $resource that gets redirected by the server (with a 301 response code): the request gets canceled and fails.

I can observe this behavior in two scenarios:

- $resource than removes the trailing slash when doing a POST (calls ws/transaction, server redirects to ws/transaction/)
- when doing e2e testing: the karma proxy redirects my REST calls and the request fails. If I enter the URL in the browser address bar (localhost:9876/ws/transaction) I can see the right result, the redirection being followed by the browser. Please note that in that case, all other requests (for static content) succeed properly...

So I am wondering what behavior would prevent $resource to follow redirections in my scenarios...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was not on AngularJS side but on server side.

Apache was appending trailing slashes to the URL and redirecting.

Had to tweak my .htacess file:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /angular/ws/index.php?type=$1&id= [QSA,L]
```

where index.php is a quick and dirty script used to mimick a RESTful server.

Now everything is working properly !